# Hypergeometric series

Tags: special-functions

If found that : "Assume further that this equation has e series solution $\sum a_ix^i$   whose coefficients are connected by two term recurrence formula. Then, such a series can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric series." [[Bragg, 1969]](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-143-00/S0002-9947-1969-0248439-9/S0002-9947-1969-0248439-9.pdf)

how can we do this conversion?

thanks in advance

Comment: A bit more context and/or an example would be nice. Also, a quote should go with a reference.

Comment: I would both like to know what "this equation" is and what kind of coefficients your two term recurrence is allowed to have.

Comment: Here is the reference : "Hypergeometric operator series and related partial differential equations", [Bragg,1969]

Comment: Satisfied with my answer?

Answer (score 5):

The (freely downloadable) book [A = B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), by Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger, is, generally speaking, a must-read. The authors explain, in particular how to deduce a hypergeometric series from a recurrence relation and the other way round.